# "Your something with title ..." or "Your something with the title ..."?

Tags: articles

In our software we are showing a status message when submitting something with a certain title.

Which wording is more correct for such a message?

> Your abstract with title "foo" has been received.

or

> Your abstract with the title "foo" has been received.

Comment: Your abstract titled "foo" has been received. Your abstract "foo" has been received. Abstract "foo" has been received. The shorter the better.

Answer (score 2):

**Your abstract with the title "foo" has been received.**

A particular title that says "foo" not some title "foo".

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/the